# Java Servlet -- Redirect to .HTML file

Tags: html, servlets

I have some java code in a servlet which I want the user to re-directed to an HTML file via a link:

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

     //...

     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
     sb.append("<a href=\"login.html\">Login</a>")

     //...
    }
```

Given that this is syntatically correct, the servlet will produce a link. The link shows me ERROR 404: Project/login.html

The url-mapping in the web.xml for Project uses /login for the LoginServlet. But I dont want to be directed to the LoginServlet. I neeed to be directed to the login.html that is in my WEB-INF under WebContent project directory.

Comment: My login.html does not have a little arrow pointing north west

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every file under WEB-INF, by design, is not accessible from the outside. That's where you store stuff (like your classes) that you do **not** want to expose on the web.

Your login.html file should be at the root of the war file, next to the WEB-INF directory, and not inside.

Comment: It was where the login.html was placed. Indeed, thanks for your response.