# Hyperlink `<a>` not invoking a mapped Servlet. Returning 404: Resource not found

Tags: html, servlets, http-status-code-404

What it says on the title. I'm trying to invoke a servlet to create a page when I click on a link. Attached below is the code.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>NavBar</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sheet.css">
</head>
<body>        
    <section class="ft_root">
        <div class="ft">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/entry/test.html"> 1 </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> 2 </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> 3 </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> 4 </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> 5 </a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

</html>
```

---

Web.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>entry_page_gen</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Servlets.entry_page_gen</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>entry_page_gen</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/entry/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>       
</web-app>
```

---

entry_page_gen.java

```
package Servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author oras
 */
@WebServlet(name = "entry_page_gen", urlPatterns = {"/entry/*"})
public class entry_page_gen extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet entry_page_gen</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet entry_page_gen at " + request.getContextPath() +     "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign     on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

---

entry_page_gen.java is stored in a package called Servlets.

What's going wrong? If more information is needed, please ask. I didn't want to bog down the question with info that might not be needed.

A point to note is that if I change the `Web.xml -> <servlet-mapping> -> <url-pattern>` to `/entry_page_gen` and call the servlet from a `<form>` with the `action` parameter, everything works fine.

P.S: I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907482/call-a-servlet-on-click-of-hyperlink) while creating the above pieces of code.

Comment: So, you want to display the content of your HTML file instead of the content created in the servlet, right?

Comment: Is your web app deployed as a ROOT application of your servlet container?

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a solution for you.

entry_page_gen.java (By the way you should change this name to follow the java convention)

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //processRequest(request, response);
     response.sendRedirect("hello.html");
     return;
}
```

Configuration:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Notes:

In the image you are seeing the URL http://localhost:8080/web-project/hello.html because of the redirect in the method, but you can reach this element with: http://localhost:8080/web-project/entry

The explanation of the configuration could see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26329628/1670134

Answer (score 0):

As answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659501/979590), the initial slash character refers to the path from the base URL (by default the domain name, unless changed with a `<base>` HTML element). So if your app URL is `http://www.example.com/myapp`, then an anchor `<a href="/entry/test.html"> 1 </a>` will refer to `http://www.example.com/entry/test.html`, therefore the servlet is not called.

You could change the anchor's href to this `<a href="/myapp/entry/test.html"> 1 </a>`